# How to parse a csv file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, csv

I am trying to parse a CSV file I made in Excel. Honestly, I am not sure how to write the JavaScript. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I would be happy to credit your work.

I am new to JavaScript. I need an application where I need to search for a variable in excel(csv format). I am building this in HTML, so I need to get all this work done in JavaScript. Could anyone kindly help me in this (i.e how to access an Excel .csv file which is in a folder, read its content and compare it with a variable)?

Comment: You want JavaScript to access your file system? Not possible. If you want something that runs on the client, you're going to have to use something like a Java Applet or Flash. You CAN'T do it with JavaScript alone.

Comment: where does the file reside? in your server?

Comment: If you're on Windows you can use the `FileSystemObject` to read text files.  You'll need to read each line and split on `,`. If you have quoted values in your CSV file then that will require a bit more work.  This is not a solution if you need to serve this HTML up over the web though: typical (sensible) browser settings would forbid this type of file access.  Maybe if you explain what you're trying to achieve in a little more detail you might get some more useful suggestions.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99(v=vs.84).aspx